# how to add item in array in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make two directives communicate. I have two directives: one is **table directive**, the other one is **header directive**.
On header I have two buttons **"add"** and **delete**. I want to add an element in the list on click of add button, and delete the element when user clicks the delete button.

But the list is a different directive, how I can update the array after delete and add actions?

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iMpStNneDmIsabTnFqpP?p=preview) is my code.

```
.directive('tm',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        scope: {
        },
        controller: 'f',
        controllerAs: 'vm'

    };
})

.controller('f',function($http, $scope){           
    var vm = this;
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      vm.data = data;
    })      
})

.controller('abc',function($http, $scope){

})

.directive('h',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'header.html',
        scope: {
        },
        controller: 'he',
        controllerAs: 'h'

    };
})

.controller('he',function($http, $scope){
    var h =this;
    h.add=function(){
        alert('heelo')
    }

    h.delete=function(){
        alert('delete')
    }

})
```

I need user to push the default value `({name: 'abc', lastname: 'pqr'})` in the list when clicks the **add** button and it should update the list. When user clicks delete, it deletes the last element and updates the list.

Update plunker server  is not running

I make fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/

I need to add a item in list when add button is press..and delete an item when delete button is press

Comment: two solutions:

1) create a service who store the data. inject it in both controller. and edit / get the data from the service each time. the service is singleton

2) your directives don't have an isolated scope so they use the parent controller scope. create a variable in the parent controller scope and use it in both directives

Comment: can you add html how you use this directives?

Comment: gudy ..I added in plunker ..plunker server is down ..so I am trying to make fiddle

Comment: @Grundy here is my https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create service to share data and functions like this:

```
service('sharedData', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.list = [];
    vm.add=function(item){
        vm.list.push(item);
    }

    vm.get = function(){
        $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
            vm.data = data;
        })
    }
    vm.delete=function(item){
        // use slice for delete object from list
    }
})
```

then you must inject this service in your directives:

```
controller('he', function($http, $scope, sharedData)
```

and use `sharedData` in your functions:

```
h.add=function(item){
    sharedData.add(item)
}
```

[Here is code](https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/3/)

Comment: it automatically reflect ?

Comment: I provided u. Just add was implemented. You can implement delete as easy as abc.